# Deflate compression of bits / bytes representation

Tags: c#, algorithm, compression, deflate, quadtree

First I'll say that I have only basic knowledge about compression.

I suspected that Deflate algorithm works on resolution of no lower than byte, i.e. finding repeats, building Haffman tree, etc., with data of bytes. To prove it I wrote the following code:

http://dotnetfiddle.net/iuxE5H

In short, that code creates a sequence of 100,000 bits which are represented by two ways: First by trivial representation (each byte contains 8 bit), and second by much spaced representation - byte per bit (each byte is 0 or 1, which means that all 7 MSBs are 0). The data is created with a lot of repeats to demonstrate the compression effectiveness in the two cases. I thought that the spaced representation (byte per bit) should be no worst than the trivial one (8 bits per byte), because the Deflate algorithm should find the large amount of repeats of 0x00 and 0x01.

The little surprise was that in short length of repeating sequences (50-100 bits) the results are similar, which means that Deflate do finds repeats of sub-byte sequences. The big surprise was that in longer length of repeating sequences (500-1,000 bits) the results was better in factor of 6 for the non-spaced bits representation - which means that the Deflate algorithm was very uneffective by finding the 0x00 and 0x01 repeats!

So the first question is: Why does Deflate could not find those repeats?

Here goes the background for the question, and another question after this.

**Background:**

I'm trying to find a compact representation a data structure. This is a quadtree-like structure which is an output of some algorithm. The representation have two parts: The structure (nodes / leafs) and the data itself. This question deals with the representation of the first part - the structure of the data structure.

The structure is created on a server side using a recursive algorithm of the following form:

```
INode CreateSubTree(input)
{
    if (mathematical-condition)
        return new Leaf(...);

    INode left = CreateSubTree(sub-input);
    INode right = CreateSubTree(sub-input);
    return new Composite(left, right);
}
```

In the data structure compact representation, I'm saving a log of the mathematical conditions (each log item is true/false) at the same order they were calculated. Then on the client side I can recycle the exact structure without needing all the methematical data.

The second part of the representation is the data of the nodes. As I already have the structure I only need to keep the raw data by a well-defined order, with no need to relate it to the node, and the client side will be able to relate data to node.

The final representation is writing both parts into a stream, and then using Deflate algorithm (by .NET's DeflateStream class) to compress it before sending to client.

**Problem:**

While the data has a lot of repeat sequences, the condition log in the structure has high level of entropy And the Deflate algorithm is uneffective for that part. Compact representation is of high importance, thus I'm looking for ways to reduce the size of the representation. This is also the reason for the bits/bytes investigation discussed above.

So the second question is: Can someone think about better way to compactly represent such a structure?

Comment: You'd have saved yourself a lot of time if you simply read how Deflate works - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know the basic of the theory of the LZ77, and I followed your link to look for any detail I missed. What I cannot understand is why does the so-match-repeating 0x00 and 0x01 bytes are not reduced in the worst case to 0 and 1 bits (by Huffman tree)? I assume that in better cases of longer repeats Both bit-based and byte-based Deflate should perform the same, notice that the repeat lengths (~1000) are much smaller than the typical window length (32k).

Comment: Well, I'd guess this has something to do with the fact that .NET's DeflateStream is a stream; it's very limited in finding the best solution. Interestingly, if you set compression level to Fastest, the gap between the two broadens significantly. And note that the window size in .NET's implementation isn't 32k. I've seen 16k in the code. All in all, Deflate in .NET is more optimized for throughput, rather than compression. I think it's also limited to repetitions of 32 bytes, maximum. This can be seen as you change the repetition length randomness.

Comment: @Luann: According to the [documentation for DeflateStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx), as of .NET 4.5 `DeflateStream` uses zlib. Your comments about `DeflateStream` might be out of date.

Comment: Thanks both of you about the information. If I have any new information I'll share it with you.